# ASP.NET MVC Html Helper doesn't render attribute ID when name starts with a number

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes, html-helper

I found some strange behavior of HTML helpers for me.
It works fine in MVC 1
But have a problem in MVC 2 and MVC 3

So, I have next layout:
in MVC 2:

```
<%= Html.Hidden("123Test", "Without ID") %>
<%= Html.Hidden("Test123", "With ID") %>
```

or in MVC 3:

```
@Html.Hidden("123Test", "Without ID")
@Html.Hidden("Test123", "With ID")
```

They both generates next markup:

```
<input name="123Test" type="hidden" value="Without ID" />
<input id="Test123" name="Test123" type="hidden" value="With ID" />
```

As you can see when name starts with number then ID would not be rendered.

So my question: is there exists some setting that switch off this behavior?
Or it can be addressed to MVC developers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are using the **[HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#case-sensitive)** that states that an id cannot start with a number

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

The offending code is the `CreateSanitizedId()` method on [`TagBuilder`](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/68345#266517)

```
// File provided for Reference Use Only by Microsoft Corporation (c) 2007.
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

public static string CreateSanitizedId(string originalId, string invalidCharReplacement) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(originalId)) { 
        return null;
    }

    if (invalidCharReplacement == null) { 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("invalidCharReplacement");
    } 

    char firstChar = originalId[0];
    if (!Html401IdUtil.IsLetter(firstChar)) { 
        // the first character must be a letter
        return null;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(originalId.Length);
    sb.Append(firstChar); 

    for (int i = 1; i < originalId.Length; i++) {
        char thisChar = originalId[i]; 
        if (Html401IdUtil.IsValidIdCharacter(thisChar)) {
            sb.Append(thisChar);
        }
        else { 
            sb.Append(invalidCharReplacement);
        } 
    } 

    return sb.ToString(); 
}
```

This would need addressing to allow this when using **[HTML 5 proposed specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute)**, which will allow an id to start with a number

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain
>   any space characters.

Comment: Yes, looks like you a right. Thanks!
It would be nice if we have some switch for this situation for migration of old projects

Comment: OK, I added this suggestion to the ASP.NET MVC Issue tracker: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/9093 If you also want this behavior - please vote by previous link.